# array of selected values which I want to delete from state is not working as expected - React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of selected values which I want to delete from state.
But I am facing some issue, when my function is getting called it updates state and in next remove it removes wrong selected value.

I tried to use react setState call back but not it's not working.

```
setState(updater, [callback])
```

Code -

```
 removeItem = itemIndex => {
    this.state.todoItems.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    this.setState({ todoItems: this.state.todoItems });
  };
  onSelectedDelete = itemIndex => {
    let deleteListValues = this.state.deleteList;
    let global = this;
    deleteListValues.forEach(function(value, index) {
      global.removeItem(value);
    });
  };
```

Json data -

```
  var todoItems = [];
  todoItems.push({ index: 1, value: "Pay credit card bill", done: false, edit: false, deleted: false });
  todoItems.push({ index: 2, value: "Go shopping", done: false, edit: false, deleted: false});
  todoItems.push({ index: 3, value: "Buy flowers for wife", done: true, edit: false, deleted: false });
  todoItems.push({ index: 4, value: "Buy Cake for birthday", done: false, edit: false, deleted: false });
```

Updated provided Data..

Comment: Are you trying to delete by value, or by index? `deleteListValues` implies by value, but `removeItem = itemIndex => {...` implies by index. Is `deleteList` a list of values to remove or is it a list of indices to remove? You can't loop over the array you are mutating.

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is queueing up a bunch of state updates in a loop, but none of them correctly update from the previous state value. They all instead use the current state.

You also are trying to remove elements by index *as you are iterating over the data*, the indices will be off after the first removal, and get more off on each subsequent state update.

You can filter the array in a single pass with a single enqueued update. At each element check if the current todo's index is *not* in the delete list. Don't forget to clear out the delete list.

```
onSelectedDelete = itemIndex => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    todoItems: prevState.todoItems
      .filter((todo) => !prevState.deleteList.includes(todo.index)),
    deleteList: [],
  }));
};
```

[image: Edit array-of-selected-values-which-i-want-to-delete-from-state-is-not-working-as-exp]

Comment: `prevState.todoItems.flatmap is not a function.` I wanted to use flatmap but it seems, my browser doesn't support or may be node version is issue,

Comment: @JavascriptCoder Actually, I just realized a simple `array.prototype.filter()` can achieve filtering multiple elements and is I believe fairly universally supported in browsers.

Comment: @JavascriptCoder Since you updated and included your todo item shape I updated my solution to use `todo.index` for identifying todos to delete. I also included working codesandbox demo.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code

- one is that you are mutating the state with `this.state.todoItems.splice`
- the other is that you are using `setState` inside a loop and not using the `updater` syntax. That is a problem because `setState` is async, so myltiple calls to it that depend on current state will not work.

Use

```js
onSelectedDelete = () => {
  this.setState(({
    deleteList,
    todoItems
  }) => {
    const remainingTodoItems = todoItems.filter(item => !deleteList.includes(item));

    return {
      todoItems: remainingTodoItems,
      deleteList: []
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: let me try this, I have provided the json data also.

Comment: `onSelectedDelete = itemIndex => {
    this.setState(({ deleteList, todoItems }) => {
      const remainingTodoItems = todoItems.filter(function(item) {
        console.log(item);
        return !deleteList.includes(item.index - 1);
      });
      console.log(remainingTodoItems);
      return {
        todoItems: remainingTodoItems,
        deleteList: []
      };
    });
  };` this is working for me I am able to see `remainingTodoItems` but state is not updating,

Comment: @JavascriptCoder please post the full code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

probably that is happening because you are mutating the state directly, try copy the deleted list array.

```
onSelectedDelete = itemIndex => {
    let deleteListValues = [...this.state.deleteList];
    let global = this;
    deleteListValues.forEach(function(value, index) {
      global.removeItem(value);
    });
  };
```